# Is there a way to monitor the cpu and power consumption of an individual app on a smartwatch (android wear)?

Tags: profiling, wear-os, cpu-usage, ddms, sony-smartwatch

I was wondering if there is a way to monitor the cpu and power consumption of an individual app on a smartwatch (android wear) remotely such as through the Android studio or something little eye which is not accessible anymore ? The usual handheld apps such as power tutor and trepn doesn't fit the screen of the watch.

Any suggestions would be appreciated on somehow adapting these apps to work on watch or anything else ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used power tutor (battery consumption) and dumpsys cpuinfo for these measurements.

Power tutor does not provide correct power values when it comes to absolute values, however, it works for relative comparison of various apps (power consumption) which was the case with my situation.

http://ziyang.eecs.umich.edu/projects/powertutor/
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [System Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wearablesoftware.wearsysteminfo&hl=en) app for Android wear. Download it from Google Play. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/GtsViqD.png) of their app shows a monitoring dashboard that fits the android watch's screen.

Comment: thanks. I'll check this one. However, it seems like it doesn't have power consumption option as a whole as well as for individual apps. CPU measurements are relatively easy to find, even through Android monitor in Android studio, but power consumption is the tricky part

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can use the [Battery Historian](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian.html) to get very detailed information about wake-locks, CPU usage, VM usage, CPU temperature.. the list goes on.

After putting your watch in Developer Mode, run :`adb bugreport > battery_stats.txt` and feed the battery_stats.txt file to the battery historian. It will output detailed information about all apps and the system in general, with the option of seeing stats for the app of your choice.